# adding html into a div without id

Tags: javascript, jquery

i'm trying to add some html code with javascript and jQuery into a div without an id, but with a class

i'm trying to have it done like this, but without success...

flie.js :

```
$(".myClassName").ready(function(){
    $(this).innerHTML = "<img src=\"http://mywebsite.com/img.png\" /> <span>some text</span>";
});
```

i'm loading the .js file with this html code

.html file :

```
<div class="myClassName">
</div>
<script>
(function()
{
    if (window['ImportFlag'] == undefined || window['ImportFlag'] == void 0) {
        var myScript = document.createElement('script');
        myScript.type = 'text/javascript';
        myScript.src = 'file.js';
        var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
        s.parentNode.insertBefore(myScript, s);}
    window['ImportFlag'] = 1;
})();
</script>
```

Comment: Do you hava any javascript errors?

Comment: not with google chrome.
i haven't tested with other browsers yet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $(".myClassName").html("<img src=\"http://mywebsite.com/img.png\" /> <span>some text</span>"); 
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You may try like this

```
<div class="myClassName">
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="file.js">
</script>​
```

file.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.myClassName').html("<img src=\"http://mywebsite.com/img.png\" /> <span>some text</span>");
});​
```

Comment: Don't put quotes around `document` - it's an object reference, not a string.

Answer (score 0):

You should firs ensure that jQuery is loaded BEFORE loading file.js. Then you should use jQuery's functions to set the div inner HTML.

This is a minimalist example :

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<div class="myClassName">
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script>
(function()
{
    if (window['ImportFlag'] == undefined || window['ImportFlag'] == void 0) {
        var myScript = document.createElement('script');
        myScript.type = 'text/javascript';
        myScript.src = 'file.js';
        var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
        s.parentNode.insertBefore(myScript, s);}
    window['ImportFlag'] = 1;
})();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Then, file.js :

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $(".myClassName").html("... <span>some text</span>"); 
});
```

Comment: I didn't post the whole file.js, but i'm doing this verification in it

Answer (score 0):

The [jQuery `ready()` function](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) should be called on the `document` object, not on an element. It evokes a DOM-ready handler, and can be called using the following syntax (from the official documentation):

> `$(document).ready(handler)`
>
> `$().ready(handler)` ***(this is not recommended)***
>
> `$(handler)`

Matei Mihai and muthu's answers here show you how this works for your example.